# How to click on the image selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

trying to click a input type using selenium python, input type calls image file, and added css cursor: pointer on the image, unfortunately cant click the image or the input

**Image**

[image]

**Code**

```
<input type="image" src="/images/btn_next.png">
```

**CSS**

```
input[type="image" i] 
{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

how to click on the image "Next Step" ?

I tried, but shows error

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="image"][@src="/images/btn_next.png"]').click()
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: thanks for your help buddy, issue resolved :)

Answer (score 2):

Try Use `WebdriverWait` and `element_to_be_clickable` to click on the image.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//input[@type="image"][@src="/images/btn_next.png"]'))).click()
```

---

If above code unable to click on the element try use javaScript executor to click on the element.

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="image"][@src="/images/btn_next.png"]'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You were close. To `click()` on the element you need to club up the *attributes* within the *xpath* using **and** and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[src='/images/btn_next.png'][type='image']").click()
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@src='/images/btn_next.png' and @type='image']").click()
  ```

But as you intend to invoke `click()` on the element, ideally you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` as follows:

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[src='/images/btn_next.png'][type='image']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@src='/images/btn_next.png' and @type='image']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, its working perfectly. :)

Answer (score -1):

If you run chrome then probably moving physical cursor to image and click can help. There is python package that move physical cursor to web element, selenium-move-cursor.